# Trying to remove data in Fractal by implementing ArraySerializer in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, jsonserializer, transformer-model

I've got the API working using the standard process, but I want to remove the `data` namespace from the JSON output. I see I need to implement ArraySerializer, I have been through the Fractal docs, but I can't work out where I need to added it in Laravel 5.2

I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/a/34041003) but I'm just getting the same output at the line of code I commented out:

```
class TrackController extends ApiController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tracks = Track::all();
        //return $this->respondWithCollection($tracks, new TrackTransformer);
        // Same response as the commented out line above
        $response = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($tracks, new TrackTransformer);
        $manager = new \League\Fractal\Manager();
        $manager->setSerializer(new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());
        return response()->json($manager->createData($response)->toArray());
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $track = Track::find($id);
        return $this->respondWithItem($track, new TrackTransformer);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm implementing this on a specific controller, even if I got this working, where do I add the code/class so I can get ArraySerializer output for all my controllers?

I've [posted this on Github](https://github.com/jackbarham/laravel-fractal-api/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/TrackController.php) if that helps.

Comment: first impression, i think you should move

`$response = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($tracks, new TrackTransformer);`

after you set serializer

Comment: Where would I move it to?

Comment: `$manager = new \League\Fractal\Manager();
    $manager->setSerializer(new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());

$response = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($tracks, new TrackTransformer);
`

Comment: Thanks for the response. however, I'm still getting the same result with `data`.

Comment: when you have use ArraySerializer

u can set you key this way

`$response = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($tracks, new TrackTransformer, 'MYKEY')`

without specify a key, fractal will automatically fall back to use the `data` key

Comment: Thanks, thats worked - Now I need to make it work for included items :)

Comment: for your information, there is a package call `Cyvelnet/laravel5-fractal
` may save you some times in making data tranformation

Comment: Thanks, looks good - Im going try it now.

Comment: @terrylow It doesn't work for me, gives error `{
  "message": "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"object\" given.",
  "status_code": 500
}` and this is my code `return new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($request->user->friends, new FriendTransformer(), 'friends');`

Comment: @RohitKhatri i belive you have forgotten to cast it to array or to json

`$manager->createData($response)->toArray()`

Comment: @terrylow can you please give me a working example?

Comment: @terrylow ok somehow I got it working, but still getting the `data` key instead `friends`, here's my new code `$resource = (new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($request->user->friends, new FriendTransformer(), 'friends'));
        $manager = new Manager();
        return $manager->createData($resource)->toArray();`  can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RohitKhatri please add this line `$manager->setSerializer(new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());` before you instantial fractal manager, because fractal uses DataArraySerializer which will uses data namespace

Comment: It's working now, and can you tell me how should I implement it so I don't have to write these lines again and again instead `$this->response->collection($collection, new Transformer, 'key')` ? Thanks

Comment: if you prefer not to use 3rd party packages,

then add a new method response() to your base Controller class, then instantial your fractal manager in response method and return a initialized manager

Comment: @terrylow Thank you so much, you saved my time.

Answer (score 6):

You need create own `MySerializer` extends of `DataArraySerializer` and use it instead of default. Default `DataArraySerializer` have three methods and in each of them need change return values to this:

```
use League\Fractal\Serializer\DataArraySerializer;

class MySerializer extends DataArraySerializer
{
    /**
     * Serialize a collection.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Serialize an item.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Serialize null resource.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function null()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

So you change the behavior of the serialize mechanism and get result as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad this isn't a built-in option.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [spatie/laravel-fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) package or [spatie/fractalistic](https://github.com/spatie/fractalistic), then you can remove the `data` key from the results by using the Spatie array serializer `Spatie\Fractalistic\ArraySerializer()` instead of the Fractal's default serializer.

You can use is like this:

```
Fractal::create()
   ->collection($books)
   ->transformWith(function($book) { return ['id' => $book['id']];})
   ->serializeWith(new \Spatie\Fractalistic\ArraySerializer())
   ->toArray();
```

This will return..

```
[
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2]
]
```

Instead of..

```
[
    'data' => [
        ['id' => 1],
        ['id' => 2]
    ]
]
```

Or, if you want to use the Spatie serializer globally, add it in the `config/fractal.php` file like this:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
     * The default serializer to be used when performing a transformation. It
     * may be left empty to use Fractal's default one. This can either be a
     * string or a League\Fractal\Serializer\SerializerAbstract subclass.
     */
    'default_serializer' => new Spatie\Fractalistic\ArraySerializer(),
    .
    .
    .
];
```

More info, see: [Using a serializer](https://github.com/spatie/fractalistic#using-a-serializer)